# Sort Number in a Textbox on Ascending order using keypress function - HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new in the community.

I am trying to create a simple page where in there are 3 textbox. 1st text box is where the number will be entered. For 2nd and 3rd textbox is where the result will be shows on a different format as soon as the numbers are entered from the 1st textbox. 2nd text box should show the number with a *comma* which I was able to do. **Example:** As soon as I enter a number on the first text box 22 55 01 02 the 2nd text box will show 22,55,01,02 however on the 3rd textbox it should show the same number from 2nd textbox but on Ascending order which I weren't able to do so. Tried searching for a solution already but to now avail. Maybe I am just missing something. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```js
function boxx1KeyPress() {
  var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
  var s = boxx1.value.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
  var x = s;

  var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
  lblValue.value = "" + s;

  // code for textbox 3 that didn't work
  //function sortAscending(a, b)
  //{return a - b;
  // }

  //var points = boxx3.value;
  //points.sort(sortAscending);
  //document.getElementById("boxx3").innerHTML = points;

}

function ClearField() {
  document.getElementById("boxx1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx3").value = "";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <B><br><center>PASTE  HERE</br>    
<input id="boxx1" type="text" onKeyPress="boxx1KeyPress()" 

onKeyUp="boxx1KeyPress()">
<br>

<input type="button" Value="Clear Field" onClick="ClearField()">

<br>

<br>11x5 GAMES</BR>
<span id="lblValue"></span>
<input id="boxx2" type="text">

<br> 
<br>Keno Games</br>
<input id="boxx3" type="text">
<br>
<p id="Keno"></p> 
<input type="button" Value="Ascend" onClick="points.sort(sortAscending)">

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to community @usernameon

Comment: @DjordjeVujicic did you just delete your answer? I can't see mate.

Comment: @Lioness yes I did, because I don't want other people to make fool out of me... If I have no credits for what I have created then there is no need for my answer to be here

Comment: Are you serious mate @DjordjeVujicic? All these for reputations only? I think this is learning platform.

Comment: @Lioness that's not the point... People steal my code and claim that it's their solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually incredibly simple to sort numbers in JavaScript. All you need to do is:

1. Split the initial string into an array with **[`.split(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** (splitting on a space).
2. Sort the numbers with **[`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**.
3. Join the numbers back to a string with **[`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**.

Keep in mind that as the output box is an `<input>`, you'll need to use **`.value`** instead of `.innerHTML`:

```js
function boxx1KeyPress() {
  var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
  var s = boxx1.value.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
  var x = s;

  var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
  lblValue.value = "" + s;

  // Fixed code for sorting the numbers
  var points = boxx1.value.split(" ");
  document.getElementById("boxx3").value = points.sort().join();

}

function ClearField() {
  document.getElementById("boxx1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx3").value = "";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <br>
  <center>
    <b>PASTE HERE</b>
    <input id="boxx1" type="text" onKeyPress="boxx1KeyPress()" onKeyUp="boxx1KeyPress()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" Value="Clear Field" onClick="ClearField()">
    <br>
    <br>
    11x5 GAMES
    <span id="lblValue"></span>
    <input id="boxx2" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    Keno Games
    <input id="boxx3" type="text">
    <br>
    <p id="Keno"></p>
    <input type="button" Value="Ascend">
  </center>
</body>
```

Also note that you had some slightly invalid HTML in your above snippet (primarily that `<br>` is a **[void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#void-element)**, so the tag self-closes and thus `</br>` is not valid). I've cleaned up the HTML in my snippet above.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are trying to sort something that is still a string... you have to make your string into an array first.

```
function boxx1KeyPress() {
var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
var s = boxx1.value.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
var x = s;

var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
lblValue.value = "" + s;

// get an array from our string s
var arr = s.split(',');
arr.sort(); // note that for strings or ints, the default sort is ascending

document.getElementById("boxx3").innerHTML = arr.join(',');
}
```

I used the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to get an array, separated at the commas, and the [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to turn it back into a string after it was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Convert comma separated string into Array. Use array sort function and you done.

```js
function boxx1KeyPress() {
  var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
  var s = boxx1.value.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
  var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
  lblValue.value = "" + s;
  
}

function sortDisending() {
   var numberArray = document.getElementById("boxx2").value.split(",");
  numberArray.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = numberArray;
  }
  
  function sortAsending() {
   
    var numberArray = document.getElementById("boxx2").value.split(",");
  numberArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = numberArray;
  }

function ClearField() {
  document.getElementById("boxx1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("boxx3").value = "";
}
```

```html
<B><br><center>PASTE  HERE   
<input id="boxx1" type="text" onKeyPress="boxx1KeyPress()" 

onKeyUp="boxx1KeyPress()">
<br>



<br>

<br>11x5 GAMES
<span id="lblValue"></span>
<input id="boxx2" type="text">

<br> 
<br>Keno Games
<input id="boxx3" type="text">
<br>
<p id="Keno"></p> 
<input type="button" Value="Ascend" onClick="sortAsending()">
<input type="button" Value="Descend" onClick="sortDisending()">

<input type="button" Value="Clear Field" onClick="ClearField()">
```